# Unity - Managing states with coroutines, won't acknowledge while loop

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm simply trying to do basic state managing so that the program does not just run right through but waits for some kind of response of the player. Right now it just jumps over the while loop and the line "Test1" is never printed, it goes straight to "Proceeding". I do have some other scripts running but none of them are using the update loop and shoulnd't impact this one.

This is my first post here so please inform me if there's something I should know about policies etc.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int turn;
    public float turnDelay = 1f;
    private WaitForSeconds turnWait;
    private bool turnOver = false;

    void Start ()
    {
        turnWait = new WaitForSeconds(turnDelay);
        turn = 1;

        ResetAndSetup();
        Debug.Log("Starting");
        StartCoroutine(GameLoop());
    }

    IEnumerator GameLoop()
    {

        yield return StartCoroutine(RoundFirstPlayer());
        Debug.Log("Proceeding");
        yield return StartCoroutine(RoundSecondPlayer());
    }

    private IEnumerator RoundFirstPlayer()
    {

        while (turnOver = false)
        {   
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                turnOver = true;
                Debug.Log("Test1");
            }
            yield return null;
        }   

        Debug.Log("Test2");
    }

    private IEnumerator RoundSecondPlayer()
    {

        yield return null;

    }

    void ResetAndSetup()
    {
        ColumnManager.ResetColumns();
    }

}
```

Comment: Change tag to **Unity3D**

Answer (score 1):

You made small mistake:

Instead

```
while (turnOver = false)
```

Use

```
 while (!turnOver)
```

or

```
while (turnOver == false)
```

Comment: Oh my god! I've been at this for so long. Thank you so much, you made my day!

Comment: I was going to delete this question since I can't see that it adds much to the community. But when I press delete it warns me that I shouldn't and that my account might get blocked from asking. What should I do?

Comment: I think just accept the answer and move on. Mistakes like that are normal for us programmers.

Comment: Hi @chrisflodin, you need to straightaway "Tick" any useful answer, to keep the board tidy, and to get yourself points so that you can ask more questions in the future.  Cheers